# In my Django application i want to print one reciept, for that i am fallowing xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

In my Django application i want to print one reciept, for that i am fallowing html to pdf convert then in pdf automatically print options is there.
for that i am install python-pisa module and i has fallowing code but my common css is not apply how is it work..

Answer (score 0):

Not all CSS styles are supported by pisa, check out

http://xhtml2pdf.appspot.com/static/pisa-en.html

There are also custom layout definitions for pisa (same link), so if you want to generate it straight from django you should define a different template for this purpose.